# Adding Simple XML Element with PHP that has a Colon

Tags: php, xml

I am attempting to add an XML attribute with PHP that contains a colon.

I want it to look like this:

```
<record xsi:schemaLocation="http://abc.com/abcItem file:///somename.xsd">
```

I attempted to add the attribute like this:

```
$record_xml->addAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation','http://abc.com file:///somepath/somename.xsd');
```

but the resulting XML is:

```
<record schemaLocation="http://abc.com/abcItem file:///somepath/somename.xsd">
```

Comment: The 3rd argument passed to `SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute` is namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the *namespace prefix* (the part before the colon), you must also include the corresponding *namespace URI* (as the third argument):

```
$record_xml->addAttribute(
    'xsi:schemaLocation',
    'http://abc.com file:///somepath/somename.xsd',
    'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
);
```

Comment: You shopuld add `xsi:` prefix to the attribute name too, as you mentioned.